# How to hit a rest service with authentication in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

This is my code but i am getting unauthorised(401) error,i have used CORS filter on server side but still i am not able to hit the API

```
var authdata = Base64.encode("username:password");

var data={};

var config = {
    headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;',
            'Authorization' : 'Basic'+ authdata,
            'Accept':'application/json'

    }
};

function fetchAllUsers(){
    ViewRecord.fetchAllUsers(REST_SERVICE_URI,data,config)
        .then(
        function(d) {
            self.users = d;
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching Users');
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a space after `Basic` in the authorization header.

```
// Bad
'Authorization' : 'Basic'+ authdata,

// Good
'Authorization' : 'Basic '+ authdata,
```